# generate a column delta based on a constraint

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe :

```
date_1     Count
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
01/09/2019  21
```

I want to generate a column delta such that 60% of the count values(rounded off) have value 2 and rest have 4.

for example for date_1 = 01/09/2019 has 21 entries, so 0.6 * 21 = 12.6 ~ 13 values have delta as 2 and remaining have delta as 4

**Expected output :**

```
date_1     Count   delta
01/09/2019  21     2
01/09/2019  21     2
01/09/2019  21     2
01/09/2019  21     2
01/09/2019  21     2
01/09/2019  21     2
.           .      . 
.           .      .
01/09/2019  21     4
01/09/2019  21     4
01/09/2019  21     4
```

Can anyone help in achieving the same.

Comment: Is this ~60% split done separately within each unique date?

Comment: @ALollz yes. each unique date has a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) to transform Column Count in a Serie with 2or 4 using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) 
to fill 60% of the length with 2 and 40% with 4:

```
df['delta']=df.groupby('date_1')['Count'].transform(lambda x: np.where ( (x.reset_index(drop=True).index+1 < round(len(x)*0.6)),2,4)  ).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
print(df)

        date_1  Count  delta
0   01/09/2019     21      2
1   01/09/2019     21      4
2   01/09/2019     21      2
3   01/09/2019     21      2
4   01/09/2019     21      2
5   01/09/2019     21      2
6   01/09/2019     21      4
7   01/09/2019     21      2
8   01/09/2019     21      4
9   01/09/2019     21      2
10  01/09/2019     21      2
11  01/09/2019     21      4
12  01/09/2019     21      4
13  01/09/2019     21      2
14  01/09/2019     21      4
15  01/09/2019     21      4
16  01/09/2019     21      4
17  01/09/2019     21      2
18  01/09/2019     21      4
19  01/09/2019     21      2
20  01/09/2019     21      2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am not getting the desired output. I tried running your code and it is giving me all delta values as 2's for date_1. Does it has anything to do with the fact that there are other columns in the dataframe as well?

Comment: Is Count a function in your code, I am assuming its the column name as mentioned in the question as well

Comment: Count is the column count

Comment: I have included reset index in the lambda function .Try now, I have updated the code:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201845/discussion-between-dper-and-ansev).